# Using R from Scala and invoking Scala from R?

Tags: r, scala

Do you know something about possibilites of

- invoking Scala from R and
- using R (libraries) from within Scala?

Best regards

Raffael

Comment: Hi Everyone. One way, maybe not particular for this situation, would be to use a Restful service. However, in R it's only possible to access other Restful Services and not to provide a Restful Service. So a http package (or lib) in R would be needed that support http's PUT and DELETE. There is a package that serilized R Data structures to XML (forgot which one) so this would be easy. Are there any pointers for a http package? I like the R.rsp package for httml GET, but what to use for PUT and DELETE? Final goal would be to combine R and haskell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if there is direct Scala interface, but rJava http://www.rforge.net/rJava/ should help.

Answer (score 22):

Check out the [jvmr package](http://dahl.byu.edu/software/jvmr) in R available on CRAN.  It allows you to:

1. embed the R interpreter in Scala
2. embed the Scala interpreter/compiler in R.

It also allows you to do the same with Java.  An article describing its usage is [here](http://dahl.byu.edu/software/jvmr/dahl-payne-uppalapati-2013.pdf).  (Disclosure: I'm the author.)

Comment: Very helpful. I'd love to see someone use this to create a clean Scala adapter to trellis/lattice graphics/plotting. Forget JFreeChart, JMathPlot, etc., R plotting is the win!

Comment: @David: Thanks for this post. It was very helpful and I was successfully able to get the R interpreter working in scala but i am not sure how to use some of the R Function in scala e.g like (scan, laply..etc) i would also like to know how to add libraries like plyr and other tools from scala. Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @Pawan Me too, I'd like to know how to add R libraries. Have you found a solution ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Check my response above. I have using jvmr to achive this. I can send you the zip source if needed.

Comment: @David, would it be possible to deploy this to a public maven repository? thanks

Answer (score 15):

There is an R package on CRAN for exactly this purpose, called "rscala". It allows bi-directional calling (R from Scala and Scala from R), as well as callbacks (eg. calling back to R from Scala code called from R). It is [well documented](http://dahl.byu.edu/software/rscala/). This package replaces the "jvmr" package mentioned in another answer.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to achieve it using jvmr. The code below is sample apache spark application i am running from scala console.

```
package org.scala.rtest

import org.ddahl.jvmr.RInScala

object RIntegration {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
       val R = RInScala()
       R>"""
            require(sparkR)

            score.sentiment = function(sentences, pos.words, neg.words, .progress='none')
                {
                  require(plyr)
                  require(stringr)


                  scores = laply(sentences, function(sentence, pos.words, neg.words) {

                    # clean up sentences with R's regex-driven global substitute, gsub():

                    sentence = gsub('[[:punct:]]', '', sentence, ignore.case=T)

                    sentence = gsub('[[:cntrl:]]', '', sentence, ignore.case=T)

                    sentence = gsub('\\d+', '', sentence, ignore.case=T)

                    # and convert to lower case:

                    sentence = tolower(sentence)

                    # split into words. str_split is in the stringr package

                    word.list = str_split(sentence, '\\s+')

                    # sometimes a list() is one level of hierarchy too much

                    words = unlist(word.list)

                    # compare our words to the dictionaries of positive & negative terms

                    pos.matches = match(words, pos.words)
                    neg.matches = match(words, neg.words)

                    # match() returns the position of the matched term or NA
                    # we just want a TRUE/FALSE:

                    pos.matches = !is.na(pos.matches)

                    neg.matches = !is.na(neg.matches)

                    # and conveniently enough, TRUE/FALSE will be treated as 1/0 by sum():

                    score = sum(pos.matches) - sum(neg.matches)

                    return(score)

                  }, pos.words, neg.words, .progress=.progress )
                  scores.df = data.frame(score=scores, text=sentences)
                  return(scores.df)
                } 


       """

        R(" x <- scan('positive-words.txt',what='character',comment.char=';')")
        R(" y <- scan('negative-words.txt',what='character',comment.char=';')")
        R(" z <- scan('twitterstream1.txt', what='character' )")

        R.eval("df <- score.sentiment(z,x,y)")  
        println(R.capture("df"))

        }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

One can use [rJava](http://www.rforge.net/rJava/) but I'm not confident that this is the best way.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/hughleat/scala2R

I wrote this while learning Scala.  Not sure if it works anymore.  It was a little DSL wrapping JRI.  Probably macros et al could do a lot better now.

Answer (score 1):

[JRI](http://www.rforge.net/JRI/) which is part of [rJava](http://www.rforge.net/rJava/) might be what your looking for